# Ant compilation having erros but the final status showing success

Tags: jenkins, build, ant

Today i have seen a weird behavior in my Jenkins build compilation log. I see it is displaying some errors while compiling the code due to some missing arguments, but it is not ending the build with final status ERROR/FAILED. The final status of the build is showing as success.

I have tried to run the build with updated java version(1.8_101) still the issue is same. Can anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Can you share logs?

Comment: below is the console log. you can find the build is going on even it had errors.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HSxLo5b.png

Comment: is this issue have you seen today and previous days its working fine?

Comment: Murali, i have observed this behavior two times in the past one month